Bluetooth audio quality does not improve when switching headset to "High Quality"
I'm using a Sony WH-CH720N Bluetooth headset. As with most Bluetooth headsets, it has two audio profiles in the setting manager: high quality and "headset/handsfree".

However, I get tinny, poor audio quality no matter which of these two I use. The same headphones sound just fine with my phone, but Ubuntu can't seem to actually use the high quality mode, even though the GNOME settings manager tells me that's what it's using.
Rebooting corrects the issue, but I'd rather it not happen in the first place.
Ubuntu 22.04
